# DbContext not working, connection string is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telerik, entity-framework-core

I'm new to MVC & .net core so I'm not sure how to resolve this in my particular case. The telerik example is overly complex I feel, but perhaps I'm not understanding something I should.

I'm trying to get the Telerik Treelist control to work: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/treelist/editing.
My table `OrgStructures` is a self referencing table with `OrgId` and `ParentId`

I want to select data from my table `OrgStructures` using a simple LINQ command but I'm facing an error and I don't know where to start, but I suspect the dbcontext (`ITContext`) is incorrect.

What works is there are other controllers in my app that works fine, but it's structured differently from the Telerik example.

**What works:**

```
namespace IT.Web.Controllers
{
    [BreadCrumb(Title = "User Management", UseDefaultRouteUrl = true, Order = 0)]
    public class UserController : BaseController
    {
        public UserController(ITContext dbContext, IConfiguration config) : base(dbContext, config)
        {
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            UsersViewModel usersVm = new UsersViewModel();
            LoadItemLists(usersVm);

            if (!_sessionUser.IsApplicationAdministrator)
            {
                usersVm.Roles.Remove(usersVm.Roles.Where(o => o.Value == OCWebHelper.Role.ApplicationAdministrator.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
            }

            return View(usersVm);
        }

         public IActionResult GetAllForGroup([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int groupId)
        {
            var users = _db.GroupUsers
                        .Where(o => o.GroupUserId == groupId)
                        .Include(o => o.User)
                        .OrderBy(o => o.User.LastName).ThenBy(o => o.User.FirstName)
                        .Select(o =>
                          new UserViewModel
                          {
                              Id = o.User.Id,
                              LastName = o.User.LastName,
                              FirstName = o.User.FirstName,
                              Username = o.User.Username,
                              Email = o.User.Email                              
                          });

            return Json(users.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

**My appsettings.json:**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=1.11.11.1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyID;Password=MyPW"
  },
```

**My action(What doesn't work):**

```
public virtual IList<OrgStructureModel> GetAll()
{

    using (var db = GetContext())
    {
        var result = Session.GetObjectFromJson<IList<OrgStructureModel>>("OrgStructure");

        if (result == null || UpdateDatabase)
        {
            result = db.OrgStructures
                .ToList()
                .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentId == org.OrgId).Count() > 0))
                .ToList();

            Session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**The Error:**

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

**My DB Context:**

```
public partial class ITContext : DbContext
{
    public ITContext()
    {
    }

    public ITContext(DbContextOptions<ITContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual ITContext GetContext()
    {
        return new ITContext();
    }

public virtual DbSet<OrgStructure> OrgStructures { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder   optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        }
    }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687");

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.GroupUserNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.GroupUserGroupUserNavigations)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.GroupUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_GroupUsers_Users1");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.GroupUserUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_GroupUsers_Users");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrgStructure>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("OrgStructure");

            entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(50)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL");

            entity.Property(e => e.Acronym)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(10)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL");

            entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentCode)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(4)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL");

            entity.Property(e => e.ParentId)
                .HasColumnType("INT")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ReportsToNavigation).WithMany(p => p.InverseReportsToNavigation).HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

**My startup.cs:**

```
services.AddDbContext<ITContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**My OrgStructureController:**

```
namespace IT.Web.Controllers
{

    public partial class OrgStructureController : Controller
    {

        private IOrgStructureService orgStructure;

        public OrgStructureController(
            IOrgStructureService service)
        {
            orgStructure = service;
        }



        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public JsonResult All([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var result = GetDirectory().ToTreeDataSourceResult(request,
                e => e.OrgId,
                e => e.ParentId,
                e => e
            );

            return Json(result);
        }

        public JsonResult Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, OrgStructureModel org)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                orgStructure.Delete(org, ModelState);
            }

            return Json(new[] { org }.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        public JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, OrgStructureModel org)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                orgStructure.Insert(org, ModelState);
            }

            return Json(new[] { org }.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        public JsonResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, OrgStructureModel org)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                orgStructure.Update(org, ModelState);
            }

            return Json(new[] { org }.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        private IEnumerable<OrgStructureModel> GetDirectory()
        {
            return orgStructure.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**My OrgStructureService:**

```
namespace IT.Web.Services
{
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using IT.Web.Models;
    using IT.Data.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class OrgStructureIEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static OrgStructureModel ToOrgStructureModel(this OrgStructure org, bool hasChildren)
        {
            return new OrgStructureModel
            {
                OrgId = org.OrgId,
                ParentId = org.ParentId,
                Name = org.Name,
                DepartmentCode = org.DepartmentCode,
                Acronym = org.Acronym,
                hasChildren = hasChildren
            };
        }
    }


    public class OrgStructureService : ITContext, IOrgStructureService
    {
        private static bool UpdateDatabase = false;
        private ISession _session;

        public ISession Session { get { return _session; } }

        public OrgStructureService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
        }

        public virtual IList<OrgStructureModel> GetAll()
        {
            using (var db = GetContext())
            {
                var result = Session.GetObjectFromJson<IList<OrgStructureModel>>("OrgStructure");

                if (result == null || UpdateDatabase)
                {
                    result = db.OrgStructures
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentId == org.OrgId).Count() > 0))
                        .ToList();

                    Session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", result);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }


        public virtual void Insert(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {

                if (!UpdateDatabase)
                {
                    var orgs = GetAll();
                    var first = orgs.OrderByDescending(e => e.OrgId).FirstOrDefault();
                    var id = (first != null) ? first.OrgId : 0;

                    org.OrgId = id + 1;

                    orgs.Insert(0, org);

                    Session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", orgs);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var db = GetContext())
                    {
                        var entity = org.ToEntity();

                        db.OrgStructures.Add(entity);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        org.OrgId = entity.OrgId;
                    }
                }

        }

        public virtual void Update(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
                if (!UpdateDatabase)
                {
                    var orgs = GetAll();
                    var target = orgs.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OrgId == org.OrgId);

                    if (target != null)
                    {
                        target.Name = org.Name;
                        target.Acronym = org.Acronym;
                        target.DepartmentCode = org.DepartmentCode;
                        target.ParentId = org.ParentId;
                    }

                    Session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", orgs);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var db = GetContext())
                    {
                        var entity = org.ToEntity();
                        db.OrgStructures.Attach(entity);
                        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

        }

        public virtual void Delete(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (!UpdateDatabase)
            {
                var orgs = GetAll();
                var target = orgs.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OrgId == org.OrgId);

                if (target != null)
                {
                    DeleteSessionChildren(target, orgs);

                    orgs.Remove(target);
                }

                Session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", orgs);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var db = GetContext())
                {
                    var entity = org.ToEntity();
                    db.OrgStructures.Attach(entity);
                    DeleteEntityChildren(entity);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DeleteEntityChildren(OrgStructure org)
        {
            using (var db = GetContext())
            {
                var children = db.OrgStructures.Where(e => e.ParentId == org.OrgId); 

                foreach (var subordinate in children)
                {
                    DeleteEntityChildren(subordinate);
                }

                db.OrgStructures.Remove(org);
            }
        }

        private void DeleteSessionChildren(OrgStructureModel org, IList<OrgStructureModel> orgs)
        {
            var subordinates = orgs.Where(m => m.ParentId == org.OrgId).ToList();

            foreach (var subordinate in subordinates)
            {
                DeleteSessionChildren(subordinate, orgs);

                orgs.Remove(subordinate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model IT.Web.Models.OrgStructureModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Org Structure";
}

@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<IT.Data.Models.OrgStructure>()
    .Name("treelist")
    .Toolbar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add().Field(e => e.Name).Width(220);
        columns.Add().Field(e => e.Acronym).Width(100);
        columns.Add().Field(e => e.DepartmentCode);
        columns.Add().Width(300).Command(c =>
        {
            c.CreateChild().Text("Add child");
            c.Edit();
            c.Destroy();
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new
        {
            style = "text-align: center;"
        });
    })
    .Editable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "OrgStructure"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("All", "OrgStructure"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "OrgStructure"))
        .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Destroy", "OrgStructure"))
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.OrgId);
            m.ParentId(f => f.ParentId);
            m.Expanded(true);
            m.Field(f => f.Name);
            m.Field(f => f.Acronym);
            m.Field(f => f.ParentId);
            m.Field(f => f.DepartmentCode);
        })
    )
    .Height(540)
)

<style>
    .k-treelist .k-command-cell .k-button {
        min-width: 0px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
</style>
```

**My IOrgStructureService:**

```
namespace IT.Web.Services
{
    public interface IOrgStructureService
    {
        IList<OrgStructureModel> GetAll();
        void Insert(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
        void Update(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
        void Delete(OrgStructureModel org, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
    }
}
```

It looks like the coding structure in the app is very different from the Telerik example since the Telerik has an additional Service layer which is confusing to a beginner to get to work within the current app structure. I've traced the error and the `OrgStructure` table query is empty.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks like you haven't read anything about how to build for ASP.NET MVC Core and EF Core. You are completely bypassing the dependency injection framework which is why you are getting these errors. I suggest you go back to basics and try and understand these first.

Comment: in GetAll method, a new context is instantiated using `db = GetContext()`. Instead use the _db from the Controller

Comment: @Matt.G How do I get the _db into my `OrgStructureService.cs`? I attempted to do this but it's linked to `BaseController` but I'm not sure how to add `public OrgStructureService(ITContext dbContext, IConfiguration config) : base(dbContext, config)
    {
    }` into this `public class OrgStructureService : ITContext, IOrgStructureService
    {`

Comment: @DavidG Is the working code using dependency injection? I'm assuming it's not.. DI makes the code difficult to follow.

Comment: DI makes it much easier if you do it right. So yes, the working code is using DI, but you are bypassing it for some reason.

Comment: not sure why OrgStructureService derives from ITContext here. Ideally OrgStructureService should have a constructor that accepts DBContext as a parameter.

Comment: DI makes the code *easier* to follow, as all you have to do is look at the constructor and you can see all the dependencies of the class. Without DI, dependencies could be anywhere and you'd have to inspect the whole class and everything it does to track them all down.

Comment: @Matt.G Just added the interface at the end `IOrgStructureService`. I think the telerik example is just poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OrgStructureService` inherits from your `ITContext`, but it does not implement any constructor that allows `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to be passed in. As a result, any time this service is injected, the internal database connection is not setup up, and hence your error.

You'd need to alter your constructor like:

```
public class OrgStructureService : ITContext, IOrgStructureService
{
    ...

    public OrgStructureService(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(builder)
    {
        _session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }
```

However, this is an *extremely* poor design over all. If anything, this service should take the context as a dependency, not inherit from the context:

```
public class OrgStructureService : IOrgStructureService
{
    private readonly ITContext _context;
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public OrgStructureService(ITContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }
```

Comment: I was missing IOrgStructureService and just added it at the end, I will give your method a try.

Comment: What should be in place of `base(builder)` at the bottom code block? I'm getting a red underline here

Comment: Sorry. That was copy-paste error. I copied the code block above it to modify that rather than typing it all from scratch and neglected to remove that bit. As you can from the updated code above, it should just be removed entirely.